# How do I implement an array that has 100 random elements and sorts them?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random; 

class bubbleSort
{
void bubbleSort(int arr[]) 
{
int n = arr.length; 
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
         if(arr[j] > arr[j+1] )
            {
               int temp = arr[j];
               arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
               arr[j+1] = temp;
            } 

}
void printArray(int arr[])
{
int n = arr.length; 
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
   System.out.println(); 
}



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Random rand = new Random();
bubbleSort ob = new bubbleSort(); 
arr[100] = {rand.nextInt()}; 
ob.bubbleSort(arr); 
ob.printArray(arr); 
}
}
```

So my code is a typical setup of bubbleSort. Now, as you can see my array has set a specific size of 100, and I intended to make each of the elements in the array a random integer. The problem being, my array implementation is not legal and I'm not sure how to make it legal. Can anyone help the me?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you explain your code, why is there a class ElementTable that you don’t seem to be using?

Comment: bubbleSort.java:38: error: illegal start of expression
arr[100] = {rand.nextInt()}; 
           ^
bubbleSort.java:38: error: ';' expected
arr[100] = {rand.nextInt()}; 
                          ^

Comment: "*my array implementation is not legal*" - You did not implement an array, you use the array data strcture from java.

Comment: Understood. Basically I got a compile error, it says illegal start of expression on line 8 where the curly bracket "{" opens. Then it goes to the second bracket "}" and says "; expected." which is bizarre as the semicolon is right there.

Comment: I think you have a major misconception about arrays. Each cell of the array holds one **value**. I recommend reading some tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Also, arrays are always zero-based. An array of length 100 has indices `0`, ..., `99`. Edit: now that I have taken a closer look at your code... you should read the tutorial from the beginning. I think there are some concepts that you did not yet grasp.

Comment: It is not an answer. It is a comment. As far as I see it, your question is in an inanswerable state without writing a full solution (which is not the aim for StackOverflow).

Comment: One-liner: `int[] arr = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints().limit(100).sorted().toArray();`

Answer (score 2):

```
arr[100] = {rand.nextInt()};
```

is not a valid way of initializing an array of 100 random elements. Instead I would suggest creating an array with 100 elemtnts

```
arr int[] = new int[100];
```

then use a for loop to initalize each elemnt to a random integer

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    arr[i] = rand.nextInt(100) + 1; //Will generate a number from 1 to 100 inclusive
}
```

Comment: @dementis I like your answer too, you go a little more in-depth with the explanation

Comment: Alright, this is great @Lucas_B But, I'm curious as to the why. Shouldn't we be able to just tell the array "Hey, you have 100 elements now, and each element is random!" I have been taking principles of operating systems recently, but my intel of the idea of pointers isn't deeply ingrained yet.

Comment: @Dark_Firaga I'm not really sure how to explain this other than thats the way you do it in java. A different language may allow for the streamlined approach you are suggesting. Even in that situation the computer still has to do what were doing here which is going over each chunck of memory in the array and setting it to a different random number.

Comment: @Dark_Firaga also, I'm not really sure what this has to do with pointers. In Java, you don't have to worry too much about pointers as the language deals with that for you as opposed to languages like c or c++.

Comment: @LucasB I recently learned that java uses pointers implicitly where as c++ uses them explicitly, its kind of tough to explain but when you declare Random rand = new Random(); for example, the new is a pointer to a random object in the same manner as calling public Dice() in a class called Dice is.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you didn't declare your array. You just started using arr without telling the compiler what arr is. You also can't initialize an array with a method call in curly braces and expect it to figure out to call that method 100 times.

A simplistic approach (i.e. not using streams and lambdas) is to allocate memory for the array with `new` and then give it the size. You then run through the array in a loop, calling nextInt() once per value.

```
int[] test = new int[100];
Random rand = new Random();
for(int value = 0; value < 100; value++) {
    test[value] = rand.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Ah I remember now. But I'm curious as to why you can't just assign the 100 to the first bracket? Does it have to do with primitive data types vs non primitive? Or is it just the way languages and pointers work?

Comment: @Dark_Firaga Like Lucas said, that's just how it is in Java. The language syntax has no way to initialize arrays like you tried. It has nothing to do with primitives, or pointers either, the same rules apply for all. If you really wanted to initialize your array with brackets, you would have to say `rand.nextInt()` 100 times in curly braces. You would also not specify the size of the array then, java just infers it from the number of objects in the initializer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to code generation<sup>1</sup>, you can assign the elements when you declare the array:

```
int[] arr = { rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(),
        rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt()};
```

There you have it.

<sup>1</sup> `Stream.generate(() -> "rand.nextInt()").limit(100).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));` and then let the IDE format the output :)

Comment: Is that as expensive as it looks?

Comment: Well, what do you mean with expensive? It doesn't cost you a dime?

Comment: Well, I've been hitting the books hard and a concept that comes up is : "expensive". Especially in data structures. Like bubble sort being bigO(n^2) while insertion sort being bigO(n). Some methods are "expensive" because they are hard to use, hard to remember, hard to implement, or make the computing time REALLY slow sometimes, that's what I mean by "expensive".